# Download large file in php with time limit

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to create a simple script which takes a URL in a form, download the file and deliver that file to the user. Something like a proxy server, only for downloading files. The only problem is that the server has limited execution time of 10 seconds which will fail for most large files. I can't change the execution time (using `set_time_limit`) because that's blocked too. Is there **ANY** way I can get past this?

Comment: Does it have to be with PHP?  If all scripts are blocked from running beyond 10 seconds, there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: Shared hosting? Or something else?

Comment: @Ares Yes shared hosting.

Comment: @Brad Actually, I don't care how it's done. I just want to download the file.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, Do you have shell access?  Can you run `exec()` from PHP, or other?

Comment: @Brad not sure. How can I check?! I tried running `exec("wget -o $file $url");` but the file is not created. So I'm guessing I can't access that either.

Comment: BTW, the host is 000webhost.com. If there is a free host that lets me download the file, that would help too.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, 000webhost.com doesn't let you do anything.  Get a new web host.

Comment: Do you need to know once the file has finished downloading? Or can you go and check later?

Comment: @Ares I can go back to check later. I'm using this for myself.

Comment: @Brad do you have anything in mind? Do you know any host that lets me do this?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori, Buy a VPS and you can do whatever you want with it.  https://www.digitalocean.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can use an cloud storage service to store the file for you

1. [google drive api](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001954.html)
2. [dropbox-php](https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API)

to "deliver" the file to the user you  share the link on your cloud storage service.

Ps: Sorry for the previous wrong answer, ftp_get only works if you are trying tpo get it from an ftp server

Answer (score 1):

Get a new web host, a cheap one that I can recommend is [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?90832) which is pretty darn cheap and they have a lot of PHP ini settings you can override (but not all).  Or, if you're just playing around and are looking for something temporary, I recommend AWS EC2, the micro instance is as cheap as $0.02/hour depending on the region you select and you get [1 month for free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), but most importantly, you get FULL root access.

Edit:

Forgot to mention where to view override PHP settings info: wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/PHP.ini
(sorry I can't make it a link, I'm a n00b on stackoverflow and am limited to 2 links)